# PostgreSQL does not order timestamp column correctly

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database with a column of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` type. I need to order the records by this column and apparently PostgreSQL has some trouble doing it as both

```
...ORDER BY time_column
```

and

```
...ORDER BY time_column DESC
```

give me the same order of elements for my 3-element sample of records having the same `time_column` value, except the amount of milliseconds in it.

It seems that while sorting, it does not consider milliseconds in the value.

I am sure the milliseconds are in fact stored in the database because when I fetch the records, I can see them in my `DateTime` field.

When I first load all the records and then order them by the `time_column` in memory, the result is correct.

Am I missing some option to make the ordering behave correctly?

**EDIT: I was apparently missing a lot. The problem was not in PostgreSQL, but in NHibernate stripping the milliseconds off the DateTime property.**

Comment: Could you show us a real working example?

Comment: I must admit I'm finding it hard to believe that PostgreSQL can't sort a built-in type that's been there for more than a decade.

Comment: Please provide table definition and the insert commands for your 3-element sample that fails to sort. I concur with Richard, as I'm using `timestamp without time zone` in a database and have no problems with the sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a foolish notion that PostgreSQL wouldn't be able to sort timestamps correctly.
Run a quick test and rest asured:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (x timestamp without time zone);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
 ('2012-03-01 23:34:19.879707')
,('2012-03-01 23:34:19.01386')
,('2012-03-01 23:34:19.738593');

SELECT x FROM t ORDER by x DESC;
SELECT x FROM t ORDER by x;
```

q.e.d.

Then try to find out, what's really happening in your query. If you can't, post a testcase and you will be helped presto pronto.

Answer (score 1):

try cast your column to ::timestamp like that:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY time_column::timestamp
```

Comment: Since the column is already `timestamp` (alias for `timestamp without time zone`), the cast does nothing useful.

Comment: probably isnt but ty for answering xD

Answer (score 0):

For those having similar issues it's worth checking the **level of precision** for the column.

Consider the following table and query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  create_date TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

In unit testing where a bunch of rows are inserted right after each other (within milliseconds), this will give inconsistent results. Changing the column to `TIMESTAMP(6)` instead of `0` makes it work with a higher level of precision, so rows can all be INSERTed "at once" and sorting will still work.